# XSLT to process multiple same node in xml into one row

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I am new to Xslt and i want to process XML having two same nodes but just one different property. On the basis of different property output should have two different columns on same row.
If Dataset ID starts with 8 digit number it should go into "Dataset Id 1" Column & if it is starts with 10 digit number it should go to "Dataset Id 2" column
Here is the XML-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

    <DisplayDefinitionTable>
        <columns>
            <column_entry order_num="1">Name</column_entry>
            <column_entry order_num="2">Id</column_entry>
            <column_entry order_num="3">DatasetID</column_entry>
        </columns>
        <rows>
            <row>
                <object_tag tag="45106" uid="yfVhkbLv6Vq5bD"/>
                <object_tag tag="45922" uid="BebdkpIm6Vq5bD"/>
                <row_element column="1" component_tag="45925" property_name="name">DEM</row_element>
                <row_element column="2" component_tag="45925" property_name="Id">8888431618</row_element>
                <row_element column="3" component_tag="50853" property_name="DatasetID">31661449AA</row_element>

            </row>
            <row>
                <object_tag tag="45106" uid="yfVhkbLv6Vq5bD"/>
                <object_tag tag="45922" uid="BebdkpIm6Vq5bD"/>
                <row_element column="1" component_tag="45925" property_name="name">DEM</row_element>
                <row_element column="2" component_tag="45925" property_name="Id">8888431618</row_element>
                <row_element column="3" component_tag="50854" property_name="DatasetID">8888431618A</row_element>

            </row>
            <row>
                <object_tag tag="45175" uid="HReh0zDS6Vq5bD"/>
                <object_tag tag="45922" uid="BebdkpIm6Vq5bD"/>  
                <row_element column="1" component_tag="51997" property_name="name">CEM</row_element>
                <row_element column="2" component_tag="51997" property_name="Id">8888516207</row_element>
                <row_element column="3" component_tag="52010" property_name="DatasetID">8888516207/C</row_element>

            </row>
            <row>
                <object_tag tag="45175" uid="HReh0zDS6Vq5bD"/>
                <object_tag tag="45922" uid="BebdkpIm6Vq5bD"/>

                <row_element column="1" component_tag="51997" property_name="name">CEM</row_element>
                <row_element column="2" component_tag="51997" property_name="Id">8888516207</row_element>
                <row_element column="3" component_tag="52011" property_name="DatasetID">31661809AB</row_element>

            </row>
            <row>
                <object_tag tag="44593" uid="07Uh0rzi6Vq5bD"/>
                <object_tag tag="45922" uid="BebdkpIm6Vq5bD"/>
                <row_element column="1" component_tag="52019" property_name="name">TT</row_element>
                <row_element column="2" component_tag="52019" property_name="Id">8888574081</row_element>
                <row_element column="3" component_tag="52992" property_name="DatasetID">8888574081/C</row_element>

            </row>
            <row>
                <object_tag tag="44593" uid="07Uh0rzi6Vq5bD"/>
                <object_tag tag="45922" uid="BebdkpIm6Vq5bD"/>
                <row_element column="1" component_tag="52019" property_name="name">TT</row_element>
                <row_element column="2" component_tag="52019" property_name="Id">8888574081</row_element>
                <row_element column="3" component_tag="52993" property_name="DatasetID">31691071/AC</row_element>

            </row>
        </DisplayDefinitionTable>
```

I am expecting output like

```
Name    ID  DatasetId1  DatasetId2
DEM 8888431618  31661449AA  8888431618A
CEM 8888516207  31661809AB  8888516207/C
```

Comment: Please post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: I tried following code but it is giving two rows:

Comment: Please don't try to post code in comments - edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

> If Dataset ID starts with 8 digit number it should go into "Dataset Id
>   1" Column & if it is starts with 10 digit number it should go to
>   "Dataset Id 2" column

The problem with your formulation is that if a string starts with a 10-digit number, then by definition it also starts with an 8-digit number. So, assuming those are the only two possibilities, the test should concentrate on whether the 9th character is a digit or not.

The following also assumes that the rows are arranged in consecutive pairs having a common `Id`.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/DisplayDefinitionTable">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>DatasetId 1</th>
        <th>DatasetId 2</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="rows/row[position() mod 2 = 1]">
        <tr>
            <!-- Name -->
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="row_element[@property_name='name']"/>
            </td>
            <!-- ID -->
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="row_element[@property_name='Id']"/>
            </td>
            <!-- Dataset IDs -->
            <xsl:variable name="datasetIDs" select="(. | following-sibling::row[1])/row_element[@property_name='DatasetID']" />
            <!-- 8 digits -->
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="$datasetIDs[not(contains('0123456789', substring(., 9, 1)))]"/>
            </td>
            <!-- 10 digits -->
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="$datasetIDs[contains('0123456789', substring(., 9, 1))]"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>DatasetId 1</th>
    <th>DatasetId 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>DEM</td>
    <td>8888431618</td>
    <td>31661449AA</td>
    <td>8888431618A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>CEM</td>
    <td>8888516207</td>
    <td>31661809AB</td>
    <td>8888516207/C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TT</td>
    <td>8888574081</td>
    <td>31691071/AC</td>
    <td>8888574081/C</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

rendered as:

[image]

Comment: Hi Michael, this is very good solution but as you said same node should be in consecutive and with pair, but  problem is sometimes only one node is present(another Dataset Id is empty then it will not come in to xml)

Comment: Then you need to **group** them first. Learn how to do that here: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html (assuming you're using XSLT 1.0)

Comment: Actually they are grouped only i.e they are consecutive, the problem is Dataset id2 node itself is missing from XML. only Dataset Id1 is present.(i.e. total count of rows is odd)

Comment: It doesn't really matter if they are consecutive or not.